# Filter Example - Meta data - Attribute Range

Tags: rapidminer

I am new to RaipdMiner. i used filter example to remove rows I did not want from my input data eg remove row where Attr1='AB'. But when I check the meta data, the range for Attr1 includes 'AB', have I gone wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The operator `Remove Unused Values` will remove any nominal values that are not used within the example set.